# Disabling a redirect from a url

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, google-chrome-devtools

So basically I want to disable url redirects. I want to stay in the same url. Is there a code to ensure this? I'm researching Mac Terminal Webbrowsers and the tab element inspect element on google chrome, but to no success. Anyone know of a way to disable redirects from pretty much all of my future searches using the console tab in inspect element, or mac terminal? Any other ways I'd be down to learn because I am a complete beginner, so let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: To clarify what you want is a way to stop sites from forwarding you to another URL? Say you go to `https://google.com` and it wants you go to to `https://www.google.com`, you'd rather stay at `https://google.com`?

Comment: Pretty much. I just want to avoid them in general, because some sites i go on have them; Probably for marketing purposes and I want to avoid that. I have no idea where to start. Is there a way to avoid redirects overall?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Browser's don't let users control that and no software on your computer will let that happen. You'd have to custom build a proxy that detects redirects and simply kill them and serve a custom page.

There is no protocol for what should happen if a page is redirected and the user "doesn't want it". Essentially, users don't know what they want but the server should know where to get what they ask for. If it moved to another location, just move without annoying the user. Redirects are a foundation of the web and are heavily relied on. Even making `https://example.com` go to `https://example.com/` for the homepage is a redirect.

Comment: Why was this removed from user control? On previous versions of Windows with Internet Explorer there were options to disable redirects. These are often used for harmful exploits that are used for bait and switch sites and for the most part seem to be a strange choice on behalf of browser implementers to take this control out of the user's hands. Further, making them difficult to flush from the cache while avoiding other more useful cached data just seems intentionally malicious...